# how to write AMTagView setTapHandler in swift and tap handler

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm too keen to know how to convert following objective-c code to swift

```
[self.tagListView setTapHandler:^(AMTagView *view) {
    view.tag++;
    NSString *text = [[view.tagText componentsSeparatedByString:@" +"] firstObject];
    [view setTagText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ +%ld", text, view.tag]];
}];
```

and how can I delete as remove tapped tag from TagList?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, or what you are trying to achieve. It's not clear what is meant by "how can I catch tapped element id"?

Comment: @LukeVanIn That's I want to delete as removed tapped tag from taglist.